# Работа с с вложенным курсором

Tags: процедуры, mysql

день добрый! Скажите пожалуйста,как работать с вложенными курсорами в mysql5 ? пробовал так:

```
CREATE 
PROCEDURE monter_load()
  COMMENT 'Процедура для техник-монтеров'
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_monter_id INT(11);
  Declare done integer default 0;
DECLARE list_of_monter CURSOR FOR SELECT id
                                  FROM
                                    online_monter_list;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
OPEN list_of_monter;
while done=0 DO
 FETCH list_of_monter INTO var_monter_id;/*берем ИД монтера*/
  /*Как сделать, чтобы здесь тоже еще один курсор делал селект-выборку по ИД монтера(var_monter_id)?*/
  END WHILE;

CLOSE list_of_monter;

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если второй курсор будет открываться и закрываться в итерации внешнего цикла, то достаточно         в конце сбросить флаг `done`.

Например:

```
OPEN list_of_monter;
FETCH list_of_monter INTO var_monter_id;
WHILE done = 0 DO
    OPEN cursor2;
    FETCH cursor2 INTO var_2;
    WHILE done = 0 DO
        -- Что-то делаем
        FETCH cursor2 INTO var_2;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE cursor2; 
    SET done = 0; -- Сброс флага который установится в 1 после прохода по cursor2
    FETCH list_of_monter INTO var_monter_id;
END WHILE;    
CLOSE list_of_monter;
```

Comment: Спасибо,получился!!. Но у меня почему то последняя строка дублируются при вставке. Думаю что условие нужно чтобы выйти из цикла.

Comment: Условием выхода как для первого, так и для второго цикла будет `SET done = 1`, который устанавливается хендлером. А он срабатывает когда `FETCH` не может получить строку. То-есть, при `FETCH` после того как уже была получена последняя строка по курсору.

Ошибка где-то в коде вставки.

Кстати, рекомендую пересмотреть `SELECT` в первом курсоре. Подозреваю что второй курсор может быть лишним, если в запросе первого объединить нужные таблицы...

Comment: И, для того чтобы выразить благодарность не обязательно раздавать карму, для этого есть кнопки "мне нравится" и "принять ответ" слева от текста с ответом :)

Comment: да,абсолютно.верно,насчет избыточности 2-го курсора...Благодарю.